# How to make the start Snackbar message when you click on the menu?

Tags: snackbar

How to make the start Snackbar message when you click on the menu?

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case (R.id.reset):
            number1.setText(null);
            number2.setText(null);
            //Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content) , "Text", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).setAction("Action", null).show();
            break;
        case (R.id.quit):
             finish();
             break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

It does not react.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the main activity view to display the SnackBar :

```
Snackbar.make(this.findViewById(android.R.id.content),
                "FooBar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click on menu item you can do like this:
`Snackbar.make(getWindow().getDecorView(), .....);`

Remember you MUST pass `View` object in order to show snackbar